# Xcode install target library dependency on executable Run

Tags: ios, xcode7

I have a target executable A.
A links against a target dynamic library B in the same project.
I would like that each time in Xcode, i run A (⌘R), i will get B installed into it's INSTALL_PATH on device/simulator.
I Tried to add to A post build events, a RunScript to copy B manually, and also tried to use "Copy Build Phase" on A target but it all failed. Nothing which i have tried seems to get B installed on it's target install directory.

Comment: Could you please be more specific on an error you get?

Comment: I just don't know how to do that. I have not tried anything which seems to be able install B when i launch A to run.